# Getting a delay with my internet (however my speed and ping are normal)

Tags: 11.10, networking, internet, realtek

I've been having some delay issues with my internet connection. It's hard to explain exactly what the issue is, but I can give a few examples. Also it does this with or without my router connected.

-If I try to go to any website, my browser will sit with the loading wheel seemingly doing nothing for about 10-30sec, then the page loads at full speed.

-If I go to YouTube, after about 10-30sec of staring at a white screen, everything except the video previews load, there still white squares (but they do eventually load). Then when I go to play a video, it takes between, 10-30sec for the video to start, but once it starts it almost immediately buffers all the way through at full speed. BUT, yep there's more, about 10-20sec after the video starts it gets paused so the commercial can play...the commercial that should have played before the video ever started.

I have 20Mb/s Down, and 2Mb/s Up, during the day I actually get closer to 30Mb/s Down and 1.7Mb/s Up, then in the evening I get about 18Mb/s Down, and 1.5Mb/s Up.

[image: Speed Test]

[image: Ping Test]

The only reason my ping test is a B is because It cant test packet loss because I don't have java, I ran the ping test on a Windows computer on the same network, and it was an A and packet loss was at 0%.

Also

```
    ping -c 4 google.com
PING google.com (74.125.45.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from yx-in-f105.1e100.net (74.125.45.105): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=33.3 ms
64 bytes from yx-in-f105.1e100.net (74.125.45.105): icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=27.5 ms
64 bytes from yx-in-f105.1e100.net (74.125.45.105): icmp_req=3 ttl=51 time=29.1 ms
64 bytes from yx-in-f105.1e100.net (74.125.45.105): icmp_req=4 ttl=51 time=29.4 ms

--- google.com ping statistics --- 
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.563/29.873/33.335/2.127 ms
```

Also, here is a link to a Kubuntu user with what sounds like the exact same issue, unfortunately the work around mentioned in the tread didn't really help me.

http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3106289.0

INFO:
Ubuntu 11.10 64bit
ASRock M3A770DE mobo W/Realtek RTL8111DL on board NIC

Comment: Slow DNS resolution? How quickly does `host google.com` respond?

Comment: which browser is this.. I had massive problems with FF loading animations (flash, canvas, CSS3) and hanging for a long time before anything would happen. I switched to Chrome and problem solved (although Chrome has it's own set of problems). I know this doesn't solve the problem but might help identify it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22750/best-way-to-set-up-dns-caching/22773#22773

Comment: @tumbleweed I'm not sure if you wanted me to put that in a terminal or not. But I did anyway, and also tried my browser, google.com loads almost instantly, probably because most of its layout is cached in my system. So I tried yahoo.com it was 40sec before anything at all came up on the screen, and at 45sec it was finished loading. I also tried dailymotion.com, it began loading after only 6sec, but didn't finish until 57sec. I'm very confused, every other computer in my home is just ridiculously fast. Also rlemon, I'm using Chromium, but have also tried FF.

Comment: @Relik: Yes I did. We debug this kind of thing with simple tools, not browsers, they have way too many moving parts.

Comment: Setup the correct DNS lookup helped me, go [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001295/976532) to check step by step solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I believe I solved the issue. A few days ago in an attempt to fix sharing issues with samba I modified the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I added `wins` before `dns` on the line that normally reads `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4` so now my internet seems to be back to normal speed, even though when I ping for example `askubuntu.com` it still takes 3000ms round trip.

And of course removing `wins` from the file made my samba shares break again.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with your nameservers, specifically that the first one or 2 in the list are timing out and your computer is only getting responses once it goes to the backups.  To check what those are set to, run the command in a terminal:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

that should output something like:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
1.2.3.4
1.2.3.5
```

With actual IP addresses.  You can try pinging each of those nameservers in order to see if they are all responding, and run some sample domain name lookups against them.  The following command will look up the IP address of google.com by asking the DNS server at 1.2.3.4:

```
host www.google.com 1.2.3.4
```

If any of the DNS servers don't respond or take a long time to respond, you know they are they ones to remove from the list.

A temporary fix is probably to remove the first item in the list and see if things improve.

A permanent fix would be to change the settings in your router to deliver only the working DNS server IPs when you connect your computer to the network by DHCP.

Comment: Both of the name servers responded fine I think. (4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms) and the other (4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms)

Comment: Even this website takes about 30sec to start loading every time I refresh it to see if there have been any new answers and about another 30sec to actually finish.

Comment: @Relik: 3 seconds round-trip is very very slow for a DNS server. Also, don't ping it, look something up, with `host`

Comment: ok I used it to look up yahoo.com this is what I got `host yahoo.com
yahoo.com has address 98.139.180.149
yahoo.com has address 209.191.122.70
yahoo.com has address 72.30.2.43
yahoo.com has address 98.137.149.56
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
` Im assuming thats what you wanted me to do was run it in the terminal, if not then just let me know because I am a little unfamiliar with that command.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for the 6-10 second or longer delay before Chrome even tries to start connecting to the internet.

In the Chrome Browser go to the pull-down menu and go to 'Settings'. Open 'Show Advanced Settings' at the bottom of the page. Go almost to the bottom of this page to the'System' section and un-check the box and turn off 'Use Hardware Acceleration When Available'.

Hope this works for you too.