# Wrong nameserver set by resolvconf and NetworkManager

Tags: networking, dns, 17.10, dhcp

My DNS server is `192.168.1.152`.

This DNS is provided to clients by DHCP. The windows clients on my LAN resolve names properly using that DNS, but my Ubuntu VM doesn't.

The VM is set up with bridge networking and is being properly provided the DNS server, but my local hostnames aren't being resolved by nslookup or browsers.

Here is an `nslookup` of one of my local domains:

```
# nslookup unraid.local
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find unraid.local: SERVFAIL
```

Here is what it should resolve by using my DNS server:

```
# nslookup unraid.local 192.168.1.152
Server:     192.168.1.152
Address:    192.168.1.152#53

Name:   unraid.local
Address: 192.168.1.152
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` has a wrong nameserver:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I ran that command. Under DNS Servers, confusingly, it specifies the correct server (and my default gateway).

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (ens33)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.152
                      192.168.1.1
```

I don't want to "hard code" the DNS server's IP in a config file because I won't be able to resolve when I change networks.

How can I get resolvconf and NetworkManager to **automatically** set the DHCP server's IP in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 84):

[Known *systemd* bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320).

[Temporary workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320/comments/8) with no need to reconfigure if the DNS IP's changes:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
reboot
```

Comment: This solution worked somewhat, host and nslookup commands resolve names properly, but wget and browsers are not

Comment: this is correct ...the current bug is that the link to `/etc/resolv.conf` comes from `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` which is bollox it should be `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` **note that `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't really exist in either case**

Comment: @FireSpore: does `ping` work then? `host` and `nslookup` resolve host names differently from `ping` or `wget`. You may need to look into `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for a solutioin.

Comment: Instead of `reboot` it worked for me to do `service systemd-resolved restart && sudo systemctl restart networking`

Comment: It worked for me even without reboot

Comment: Not a fix for me - now I just fail to name resolve quicker!

Answer (score 72):

Try editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, adding your desired DNS server:

change this:

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
```

to this (but use the one you want - this is an example):

```
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.1.152
```

after that, restart the service:

```
service systemd-resolved restart
```

And when you check the status you should see

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.152

      DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                  16.172.in-addr.arpa
                  168.192.in-addr.arpa
                  17.172.in-addr.arpa
                  18.172.in-addr.arpa
                  19.172.in-addr.arpa
```

Comment: Here is the systemd-resolve --status after changing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

https://pastebin.com/AeUFQkyB

Browsers still fail to resolve names also.

Comment: systemd is so broken.

DHCP tells the host what DNS should be, (and a bunch of other network settings) you should not have to change any files on the host for this to work.

Comment: Does not look optimal, you will have to do this every time you change DNS server/network

Comment: You would need to reconfigure every time the DNS IP's changes (for instance on different networks).

Answer (score 18):

I finally got a solution for this problem for ubuntu 17.10. By default this version of Ubuntu uses `systemd-resolved`, which I hope is going to be stable for the next versions.

In order to use custom dns instead of the local systemd-resolved cache, do the following:

1. add new nameservers. Edit the file in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` as sudoer. Here I've commented out the DNS entry and placed my dns

   `[Resolve]
   DNS=10.96.0.10 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`
2. cancel the actual symlink to `/etc/resolv.conf`
3. create a new symlink `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
4. restart the service `sudo service systemd-resolved restart`
5. restart the network manager `sudo systemctl restart networking`

And now if you dig to a name provided by your add dns, you should see the record resolved `dig  nexus.default.svc.cluster.mydomain`

Last step is to update the order of resolution in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, by placing the dns before the mdns4_minimal

```
hosts           files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] myhostname
```

Comment: You would need to reconfigure every time the DNS IP's changes (for instance on different networks).

Comment: Victor do you have a best solution? this is the same if you use static net config

Comment: This answer works for both static and dynamic configurations: https://askubuntu.com/a/974482/343617

Comment: thank you, the solution I have pointed out was static. I agree

Comment: This just worked for me on a new 18.04 install

Comment: This worked for me on Linux mint 19.1 fresh install as well

Comment: Good news its 2021 and systemd-resolved still not stable

Comment: This is what worked for me - just switching the link did not. But this should be flexible right, no matter what local network I'm on, won't 8.8.8.8 always be found?

Comment: This work for me as of comment timestamp. Kudos!

Answer (score 3):

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` is not the problem. `systemd-resolved` just defaults to unconfigured, so it fails all lookups. Feel free to rant about Unconfigured vs A Reasonable Default.

Manually add nameservers to `systemd-resolved`.
(editing per Olorin's comment below to add `mkdir`, correct path `/etc` not `/lib`, in order to survive system updates)

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/00-my-dns-server-is.conf
```

Add:

```
[Resolve]
Cache=yes
DNS=192.168.1.152
```

Then...

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

`systemd-resolved` is smart, but, unconfigured as it is, by package maintainers, it just LOOKS stupid because package maintainers do not believe in A Reasonable Default. We can put 13 internet root servers in there aka "djb way", or 10 opennic servers: https://pastebin.com/JBfYVVtG or the three fastest opennic servers, as measured by namebench. Plus ISP nameservers, sure. Plus Google, sure. `systemd-resolved` is not the problem. I am the problem.

Comment: Though you probably don't want to edit a file `/usr/lib` - those will likely be overwritten on package upgrade. I think a corresponding file somewhere in `/etc/systemd` is the way to go (it already should have an `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` ready to be edited by admins).

Comment: man resolved.conf.d, with the d, yes /etc/systemd/resolved.d is the place. I'm noticing that we often have to mkdir /etc/[path].d. bob@laptop l /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
ls: cannot access '/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d': No such file or directory

Comment: This looked very promising but my system is still using /etc/resolv.conf (/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf). I tried /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d and /etc/systemd/resolved.d my /etc/systemd/resolved.conf is also configured with the correct DNS server but i nothing is updating /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf and it seems this is the only file being used. (i also set in netplan yaml file `dhcp4-overrides: use-dns: no` for now I will need to symlink /etc/resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. Not sure if i missed anything but would really like a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

On my system I found a bad symlink: `/etc/resolv.conf` was a symlink which points to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

This file contains only one line:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53#53
```

As a result, the local network's DNS lookup was often missing.

So, instead I changed `/etc/reolv.conf` to point to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

and now works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is [posted here on my blog](https://www.ookangzheng.com/ubuntu-17-10-custom-dns/)

Use nano editor to edit these 2 files

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

Add DNS servers you want to use

```
nameserver 9.9.9.9
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Then restart the service

```
service systemd-resolved restart
```

Final check:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Do nslookup

```
nslookup google.com
```

i just used this and it fixed the problem on my laptop at home, but some time in the future when I am out of my home network I can see that it will cause problems, because the primary and secondary dns server will still be my home servers with their lan addresses.

Comment: You would need to reconfigure every time the DNS IP's changes (for instance on different networks).

Comment: it's not elegant, but it work's gcloud sometimes sabotage my bedtime.

Comment: Editing `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't work as the file will be overwritten during the `systemd-resolved` restart. Just edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. See my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/977243/ubuntu-17-10-disable-netplan/1037288

Answer (score 1):

I put together a script that works around the issue of Netplan not currently supporting the ability to supersede DHCP supplied DNS servers and domain search order.  It creates the Netplan yaml file and configures systemd-resolved to work as expected.

```
################## Start Netplan config (renderer: NetworkManager)
#  Some useful commands for customisation
# NetConn=$(nmcli device show|grep GENERAL.CONNECTION|head -n1|awk '{print $2}')
# IP=$(nmcli device show|grep IP4.ADDRESS|head -n1|awk '{print $2}')
# GATEWAY=$(nmcli device show|grep IP4.GATEWAY|head -n1|awk '{print $2}')
# sed -i 's/renderer: networkd/renderer: NetworkManager/' //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
######################################
systemctl start NetworkManager
NIC=$(nmcli device show|grep GENERAL.DEVICE|head -n1|awk '{print $2}')

#####   create Netplan yaml config file
cat >/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml <<EOF 
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
  network:
   version: 2
   renderer: NetworkManager
   ethernets:
EOF
echo "    ${NIC}:" >> /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
cat >>/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml <<EOF
      dhcp4: yes
      nameservers:
        search: [abc.domain.edu, def.domain.edu]
        addresses: [10.10.11.22, 10.10.11.23]

EOF

#work around DNS resolv bug
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sed -i 's/#DNS=/DNS=10.10.11.22 10.10.11.23/' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
sed -i 's/#Domains=/Domains=abc.domain.edu def.domain.edu' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
systemctl start systemd-resolved
systemctl restart NetworkManager
netplan apply
reboot
############### End Netplan Config
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but the only solution which worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 was the one I found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/):

First, change `/etc/resolv.conf` by setting the desired *nameserver*:

```
# nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Set, for instance,

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

And then do

```
# chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

This protects `/etc/resolv.conf` file so that no one can modify it including root user.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this again on another machine. I decided to live with systemd's resolved and with networkmanager by editing the resolved.conf file, /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, and setting networkmanager to use the same dns server. Stop the stub listener from taking over dns:

```
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf:
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.0.1
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=no
```

...then go into NetworkManager and stop nm from using dhcp to acquire a nameserver IP. Turn off Automatic for DNS, set the nameserver IP.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to get name resolution to work with Docker by disabling `systemd-resolved` completely:

```
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

Then edit /etc/resolv.conf like you would have back in the pre-systemd days.

EDIT: This approach isn't aggressive enough. If your Docker container runs for long enough, Systemd will restart `systemd-resolved` and DNS resolution will break again. Some people have reported success by running this command:

```
systemctl mask systemd-resolved
```

...which is like `systemctl disable` but stronger. In my Docker deployments I resort to removing the `systemd-resolved` binary to make sure that Systemd cannot restart it under any circumstances. The command to do that is:

```
rm -f /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did, after this happened to me when I upgraded from a much older Ubuntu release and my name resolution broke.  First I tried the 00-yadayadayada approach above - but that did NOT work.

cd /etc
mv resolv.conf resolv.conf-I-HATE-SYSTEMD
cp resolv.conf-I-HATE-SYSTEMD resolv.conf

And then edited the file /etc/resolv.conf.  The first gets rid of the pesky symbolic link (and documents that was done) so that subsequent reboots won't overwrite it (I hope).

What all of this demonstrates is THE ABSOLUTE FOLLY THAT IS SYSTEMD.  What the fsck does a resolver configuration have to do with system startup order, etc., such that systemd should be involved AT ALL.  What a piece of junk.

ARRRRRRRRGH.  What a piece of junk systemd is.  Too many programmers with too much time on their hands to lazy to do the "un fun" jobs of actually writing and fixing APPLICATIONS, seeing it as somehow "beneath" them.  Bah.

JRJ

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat` and see if /etc/resolvconf/run/interface/* is anything you do NOT want, comment it later using `vi`.

Comment: did you mean  `cat /etc/resolvconf/interface-order`  ?

you could also say: comment it later using your favorite text editor, such as, for example, `vi`

Comment: yep, you got me... but after some testing, I realized it's not because of `resolvconf`, and found it was generated by `dhcpcd`, so I edited `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and un-commended the line starts with "static domain_name_servers", and set some IP addresses separated by space.

Answer (score -3):

I have the same problem. Each reboot, nothing will resolve. I've uninstalled everything and reinstalled it about 50 times already. It's simply just broken.

so the fix is.... "just apply a few settings each time you boot your pc, which allows 90% of host names to resolve but wget and apt-get updates and upgrades will fail randomly for no reason"

cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
#MulticastDNS=yes
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=udp
```

When using Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop, you have to edit the one file that says *DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BLAH BLAH BLAH*

well that's the ONLY way it works~!

```
root@nas:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

So remove the 127.0.0.53 IP as the name server and enter another one, google for example. It appears my actual DNS IP address doesn't resolve host names either (even though it works on 10 other machines and devices in the house), but google's works fine.