# Unable to configure a secondary DNS server

Tags: 17.10, dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

Network manager wasn't applying the DNS servers that I entered using `"Edit Connections" -> "Wired Connection 1" -> IPv4 Settings -> Switch to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only -> entered in DNS servers`

`dig @10.1.0.16 internal.address` works just fine, gives me what's expected.

editing resolv.conf doesn't seem to do the trick, and just gets overwritten anyways.

`nmcli` shows that the correct DNS servers are being used

`systemd-resolve --status` shows the DNS servers as expected

again, digging the DNS servers works great.

I've tried switching to dnsmasq as a workaround, which has probably just added to my confusion.  I'm not even sure what to provide as far as logs go.  What do you guys need to help?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the `dnsmasq` line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?  Just comment it out with a `#` in front of it.  Secondly, if you want stuff to stay in `/etc/resolv.conf` you edit the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original` then when `resolvconf -u` is ran the lines are added automatically to `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: actually you may be on to something with that. the link at `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original` points to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` which doesn't exist

Comment: I went ahead and added the symlink and put my DNS servers into the `stub-resolve.conf` then restarted `network-manager` but unfortunately behavior is the same. I can resolve external but not internal resources.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 17.10 it appears

Comment: Possible solutions:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/973017/wrong-nameserver-set-by-resolvconf-and-networkmanager

Answer (score 0):

On the IPV4 tab try switching automatic DHCP to **Manual** so you will be using the values you enter for the DNS server IP addresses,

Here are [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html) for Ubuntu 16. Should work the same for V14 and V17

Comment: after making this change the behavior is the same