# Unable to start resolvconf-pull-resolved

Tags: resolv.conf

I've installed resolvconf but for some reason resolvconf-pull-resolved doesn't want to initiate, Any idea what is preventing this, I would think that it's systemd but then again i don't even know what this pull service does

```
● resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/resolvconf-pull-resolved.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2018-09-24 13:11:46 UTC; 4s ago
Process: 10656 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf | /sbin/resolvconf -a systemd-resolved (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 10656 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 24 13:11:46 Inspire systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Sep 24 13:11:46 Inspire systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
```

And journalctl

```
journalctl | grep resolvconf
Sep 24 12:58:39 Inspire sudo[9844]: root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/apt install resolvconf
Sep 24 12:58:46 Inspire systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.path.
Sep 24 12:58:53 Inspire systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service..
```

Comment: You may want to check https://askubuntu.com/questions/973017/wrong-nameserver-set-by-resolvconf-and-networkmanager

Comment: No, Everything else works but this service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the service is working fine it's just not expected to continue running. It runs this command:

```
/bin/sh -c cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf | /sbin/resolvconf -a systemd-resolved
```

Reading the man page for `resolvconf` shows:

> The resolvconf package comprises a simple database for run-time nameserver information and a simple framework for notifying applications of changes in that information.  Resolvconf thus sets itself up as the intermediary between programs  that supply nameserver information and applications that use that information.
>
> Information is added to or removed from the database using the resolvconf program.  See the OPTIONS section below for a discussion of the available options.

And the `-a` option:

> -a IFACE.PROG
>
> Add or overwrite the record IFACE.PROG then run the update scripts if updating is enabled.  When  this  option  is  used the information  must be provided to resolvconf on its standard input in the format of the resolv.conf(5) file.  Each line in the file must be terminated by a newline.

It appears it creates the resolvconf database and then exits.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sure someone will come across this via a Google search and it will help them too, plus I learned a few things about systemd for better or worse ;)

Answer (score 1):

In ordered to solve this problem you need to follow this steps.

```
systemctl start resolvconf.service
systemctl enable resolvconf.service
systemctl start resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
systemctl enable resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
systemctl start resolvconf
systemctl enable resolvconf
dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

enjoy!

Comment: Just wanted to follow your suggestion, but on `systemctl enable resolv-pull-resolved.service` I get following error:

The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) ... in next comment

Comment: 2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.