# How to make Ubuntu server 18.04 use dns-nameservers from /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, dns, systemd, systemd-resolved

On Ubuntu server 18.04 I've disabled netplan and using /etc/network/interfaces.

```
sudo apt-get -y install ifupdown

cat <<EOM  | sudo bash -c 'cat > /etc/network/interfaces'
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.5.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.254
dns-nameservers 192.168.5.53 192.168.5.5
EOM

sudo ifdown --force eth0 lo && sudo ifup -a

sudo systemctl stop networkd-dispatcher
sudo systemctl disable networkd-dispatcher
sudo systemctl mask networkd-dispatcher
sudo apt-get -y purge nplan netplan.io
```

But apparently the systemd-resolve doesn't take into account the `dns-nameservers` field.

In the `/etc/resolv.conf` it puts only this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Output of `ls -la /etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Oct  2 15:28 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Output of the `sudo systemd-resolve --status | grep -A3 Server` is empty.

I can define DNS servers in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` like this:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.5.53 192.168.5.5
```

Then the output of `sudo systemd-resolve --status | grep -A3 Server` is:

```
     DNS Servers: 192.168.5.53
                  192.168.5.5
      DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                  16.172.in-addr.arpa
```

And they are used correctly and appear in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

How to make the `dns-nameservers` config line work?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo systemd-resolve --status | grep -A3  Servers`

Answer (score 3):

You need the package `resolvconf`, too.

So, to get rid of netplan completely:

1. Configure `/etc/network/interfaces`
2. Install ifupdown and friends: `$ sudo apt install ifupdown resolvconf`
3. Remove netplan: `$ sudo apt remove nplan netplan.io`

Answer (score 1):

> How to make the dns-nameservers config line work?

As you can see by the status command, the line is working perfectly:

```
DNS Servers: 192.168.5.53
              192.168.5.5
```

The symbolic link /etc/resolv.conf shows:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

That indicates that dnsmasq is running here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

In short, this means that domain name lookups will first query a local cache to see if the site has been visited before. 127.0.0.xx is 'local' in this context. If so, the local cache will provide the IP address. If the site has not been visited before and no reference is available in the local cache, only then will the listed DNS nameservers; 192.168.5.53 and 192.168.5.5, in your case, be used.

The readings you’ve gven above are entirely normal and expected.

Comment: It's working perfectly only if you hardcode IPs into `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, otherwise the status command output is empty. So the `dns-nameservers` doesn't work at all. Sorry for the confusing description.

Comment: May we see: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Added the `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/973025/379641).

You need to edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file to change DNS on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score -1):

network interfaces files have been changed a lot on ubuntu 18.
I suggest you to check this website or another one to correctly configure your network adapter

[how to configure network ubuntu 18](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Anyways you can also (and that's the easiest way) configure your ip and nameservers from the network manager on settings.

Comment: I don't care about netplan. And the server has no NetworkManager.

Comment: On google it's possible to find how to configure netplan. If you think that my question is about configuring netplan then flag it as a duplicate.