# IPSEC/L2TP VPN causes resolving name server problem with the latest systemd version on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, systemd, bug-reporting, ipsec

After upgrading libnss-sysytemd library to the latest version `237-3ubuntu10.12`, IPSEC/L2TP VPN connection is established but I cannot connect to outside of LAN. I found out the route table was not the same as the version `237-3ubuntu10.11`. The difference is the order of the ip addresses. On 237-3ubuntu10.12, the order of the remote vpn ip address on route table is normal order but the VPN connection doesn't work well. On 237-3ubuntu10.11, the order is reverse order, then VPN connection works well.

But today, it happens again on the Starbacks WIFI even on the version `237-3ubuntu10.11`. The route table is below.

### 237-3ubuntu10.11 on Starbacks WIFI

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp58s0
10.27.40.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     600    0        0 wlp58s0
123.234.345.456 _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp58s0
192.168.10.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

### 237-3ubuntu10.11 on the mobile network tethering.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlp58s0
10.27.40.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     600    0        0 wlp58s0
456.345.234.123. _gateway        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp58s0
192.168.10.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

I'm sure it's a bug of systemd. Has anybody reported this bug yet?

I'm using strongswan and xl2tp. It doesn't cause this problem anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been fix with this solution.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
reboot
```

It was systemd bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320

[Wrong nameserver set by resolvconf and NetworkManager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973017/wrong-nameserver-set-by-resolvconf-and-networkmanager)

Answer (score 0):

The IP address with reversed ordering of the octets has a trailing dot, which indicates it is the significant part of a reverse DNS PTR record. See :

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145665/

Comment: Yes, it must be reversed order in this case. That's why I think there is a bug because it happens with only the latest 18.04. And I'm afraid your answer is not a answer should be a comment.