# How to set up a caching DNS server for my network?

Tags: server, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to set up DNS caching?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22750/best-way-to-set-up-dns-caching)

How do I set up a caching DNS server with Ubuntu?